# Jersey failing to marshall object for GET response

Tags: rest, jaxb, jersey

I am writing a REST resource and I'm having trouble with an object

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_A")
@XmlRootElement(name = "typeA")
public class TypeA implements GenericType{

@Id
@Column(name = "COLUMN_ID")
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@OneToMany (mappedBy="person")
private List<TypeB> typeBList;

@XmlAttribute
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@XmlElement(name="mytypes")
public List<TypeB> getTypeBList() {
    return typeBList;
}

public void setTypeBList(List<TypeB> typeBList) {
    this.typeBList = typeBList;
}
}
```

The interface doesn't have any annotations.

This is the resource that provides the service

```
@Path("user/{id}")
public class PersonResourceImpl {

@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public TypeA getPerson(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    LOG.info("doGetPerson() - IN");

    ... get from a datasource ...

    return retrievedPerson;
}
```

When I try and use this resource the correct object is returned from the database but when it tries to marshall it into xml it fails with Message body writer for class not found and MIME type application/xml

This is all I have had to do for other objects and they work, the only thing I havent done on any of the other is the @XmlAttribute tag maybe something is wrong there?

thanks

Comment: What's the exact exception that is thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was being caused by the way I was using Hibernate. I was loading the Object from the db and returning it to my Rest resource, at the time when I do the null check the resource is still available.

When JAXB tries to marshall this object it fails, either the object has changed and is no longer available or it doesnt have the correct annotations when hibernate creates it.

I solved this by creating a new Object and loading it with the data from the one hibernate returns.